# How to tell which derived class calling override base method

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance

I am debugging a Java application using Google Guava Event Bus. There is a HandleEvent method defined in a base class, and it's being called many times. I would like to print out each time it's called by which derived class. What kind of debugging approach can do that? I was thinking using Java reflection, still researching on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do

```
System.out.writeLine(getClass().getName())
```

In your event handler to get this information.

Answer (score 2):

To get the name of the derived class you can simply use `getClass()`:

```
public void HandleEvent(...) {
    System.out.println("HandleEvent called for "+this.getClass().getName());
    ... // the rest of HandleEvent method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if this object is `intanceof` derived class  under base class then only print

Answer (score 0):

put a beak point in handleEvent method, one the break point hits , you can see the calling frames (stack) in debugger.